# An inequality about integration...

Tags: integration, inequality

[image]

A friend asked me the above inequality which I cannot prove after some try, would someone here help me please??

Comment: What did you try? (and have you considered changes of variables such as $x=\cos t$?)

Comment: x=sint,legendre functions, expanding or some other things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can compute the integral exactly. This is a classic approach, which applies to several problems of this sort. Let $I_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx$.

- Do the change of variable $x=\cos t$. Massaging the integral and using $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$, you should get $I_n=\int_0^\pi \sin^{2n+1}$.
- By integration by parts, you can obtain a recurrence relation on $I_n$, namely
  $$
  I_{n+1} = \frac{2n+2}{2n+3}I_n
  $$
- computing $I_0$ is easy. This gives you the last building block you need to solve the recurrence relation and get the closed-form expression of $I_n$.

Comment: I use your hint to work on and find out this is exactly what I need to prove the inequality, thank you very much!!